# In materializecss, how to open the slide-out menu from right rather than default left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In materialize CSS, the hamburger menu is on left by default. I changed the CSS and achieved it to right.But on clicking, the side-nav still slides out from left. I referred the documentation but found no class for toggle menu right. I tried `edge: right` but it did not work.

I want the menu to slide out from right on clicking hamburger icon.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Add your related code here.

Comment: Have you had a look at this? http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html - the "options" section by "edge" where you get to specify the horizontal origin of the menu

Answer (score 2):

I've made you a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/8tw2u80q/3/. Hope this helps you.

```js
  $('.button-collapse').sideNav({
      menuWidth: 300, // Default is 240
      edge: 'right', // Choose the horizontal origin
      closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
    }
  );
```

You need to set edge: right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i meant in the comment below your question, after you initialize the menu, you can specify the correct options you want wit jquery and have the menu pop out on the right other than the left.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('.button-collapse').sideNav({
      menuWidth: 300, // Default is 240
      edge: 'right', // Choose the horizontal origin
      closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
    }
  );
</script>
```

This will move the menu to pop open on the right once you are in the correct screen size for the mobile menu to be displayed